# Batch command for moving files specified in a list

Tags: shell, batch-file

From a Windows console I need to move a set of files. The criteria to choose which files to move is based on content:

```
findstr /M "<content-criteria>" *.$$$ > files_to_move.txt
```

How can I launch a `move` command to process this list?

My totally wrong attempt:

```
move %1 dest_folder < files_to_move.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `for` to iterate over your text file.  Another way to do it will be to use the loop to iterate over the output of another command (in this case findstr) instead of outputting it to a temporary text file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /M "<content-criteria>" *.$$$') do move "%%a" TargetFolder
```

Comment: Thank you, that works really well. Avoiding the temp file is quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute a move operation for each of the files in the list

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (files_to_move.txt) do move "%%a" dest_folder
```

The `for /f` command will read the input file. For each line, the code after `do` clause will be executed with the content of the line stored in the replaceable parameter `%%a`. The `"delims="` clause indicates to the `for` command that no delimiter will be used to split the line in tokens.